# Adapter binding SQLlite Recordsets to Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I tried `ListView` and I tried SQLlite creating a table etc. both worked independly of each other.

Now I want the `ListView` to show my recordsets out of a test table in the database. And that doesn't work (it is the 2nd code)

The following code works, I've got my animal array without the database:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,R.layout.activity_li stview, mobileArray);          
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);  
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I tried to edit the adapter to show my records out of my database table (the database code comes from an tutorial).

```
List<ShoppingMemo> shoppingMemoList = dataSource.getAllShoppingMemos();
ArrayAdapter<ShoppingMemo> shoppingMemoArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.activity_listview,shoppingMemoList);
ListView shoppingMemosListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_listview);
shoppingMemosListView.setAdapter(shoppingMemoArrayAdapter);
```

Yes, I tried different posts and explanations but I couldn't find the error. So my question is, what's wrong with the 2nd code?

EDIT: I got the database code from here: http://www.programmierenlernenhq.de/daten-in-sqlite-datenbank-schreiben-und-lesen-in-android/

Comment: Are you seeing any error in the logs, or directly the items don't appear in the listview? It would be useful if you post your database code, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would compile: `ArrayAdapter<ShoppingMemo> shoppingMemoArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.activity_listview,shoppingMemoList);`

Comment: Pravin is right. Remove <String> in new ArrayAdapter

Comment: Yes I tried with and without String, no compiler error, the app starts, but doesn't show a ListView

Answer (score 0):

I something like found the "error".
I added an new simulator device, same versions same everything, now it shows the ListView.